# Ipad app to Iphone app

Tags: iphone, ios, css, ipad

I've created a stunning looking ipad app that fills the screen and works great. However, I'd like for it to work on the iphone as well design wise. I can use it on the iphone but all the graphics and everything are jumbo sized.

I don't want to recreate all the images and graphics and then create a new style sheet. If I must, then I will but is there a better way?

Perhaps next time just build for the iphone and let them "2x" it?

Any input would be great! Thanks.

Comment: is this a Universal app? Are you using storyboard or .Xib files?

Comment: This is marked as universal. I'm not sure the difference between storyboard and .xib. I'm using xcode with the cordova lib for phone gap.

Comment: When you use .xib files you create one file per UIViewcontroller that you want to display as a view, when you use storyboard you have all the views in the same file http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1

Answer (score 2):

In the summary options of the applications, just mark the devices option as Universal, then use the same storyboard and the same images for iPad and for iPhone, and if You don't like how some images looks in the iPhone or the iPad you can detected the device like this:

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
 // is iPad change some image or some item.
}else{
//is iPhone change some image or some item. 
}
```

I hope this can help you.

Comment: It was universal by default. But for some reason the images and text are completely blown out in the iphone simulator.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to recreate many graphics. You should be able to set almost all of them to automatically resize to the bounds of their views. This is default behavior in most cases, I think. You will have to handle resizing your views, either in the xibs or in the code.

Moises's answer covers the code case.

The UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() method is equivalent to [[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] and it saves you a bit of typing.

The easiest way to handle the xibs is duplicating the files. (You can try to use the auto-resizing tools in the xibs too, but they don't give you very fine-grained control).

The easiest way to create iPhone xibs (that I know of):

- Find your project folder in Finder
- for each xib: Right-click -> Duplicate (for some reason, you can't do this form Xcode)
- Replace " copy.xib" with "~iphone.xib" at the end of each new file's name (it's case sensitive '~iPhone' doesn't work.)
- Open Xcode and add the files into your project
- Adjust the sizes to look good on iPhone. Bear in mind that the new width for the views should be 320 (unless you want the iPhone views to be able to rotate, in which case it's a lot harder given the two different screen sizes for iPhone.)

And that takes care of it. All of your IBOutlets and such should be naturally preserved by the duplication process.

If you can get away with just adjusting the appearance to take an App from iPad to iPhone, more power to you. We had to reduce the amount of content we displayed on a lot of pages and add some new views, and otherwise generally adjust the flow of the App in the project I'm working on.